# Adding a loop to search program

Tags: java

I have the following program in which a user enter his social security number and is assigned a location that correspond to it.

One thing I do not get is how can I add a loop to search through through my array until it find the correct area number and the area it correspond to for example 3 correspond to new hampshire. I tried a loop in my program but I am not sure how to make it work.

```
import jpb.*;

public class SSNInfo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        SimpleIO.prompt("Enter a Social Security number: ");

        String ssn = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();

        while (true)
        {
            if (ssn.length() != 11)
            {
                System.out.println("Error: Number must have 11 " +
                          "characters");
            }
            else if (ssn.charAt(3) != '-' || 
                     ssn.charAt(6) != '-')
            {
                System.out.println(
                    "Error: Number must have the form ddd-dd-dddd");
            }
            else
                break;

            SimpleIO.prompt("\nPlease re-enter number: ");
            ssn = SimpleIO.readLine().trim();
        }

        // Get the area number (the first 3 digits of the SSN)
        int area = Integer.parseInt(ssn.substring(0, 3));

        int[] areaNumbers =
           {  3,   7,   9,  34,  39,  49, 134, 158, 211, 220,
            222, 231, 236, 246, 251, 260, 267, 302, 317, 361,
            386, 399, 407, 415, 424, 428, 432, 439, 448, 467,
            477, 485, 500, 502, 504, 508, 515, 517, 519, 520,
            524, 525, 527, 529, 530, 539, 544, 573, 574, 576,
            579, 580, 584, 585, 586, 588, 595, 599, 601, 626,
            645, 647, 649, 653, 658, 665, 675, 679, 680};

        String[] locations =
          {"New Hampshire",   "Maine",          "Vermont",
           "Massachusetts",   "Rhode Island",   "Connecticut",
           "New York",        "New Jersey",     "Pennsylvania",
           "Maryland",        "Delaware",       "Virginia",
           "West Virginia",   "North Carolina", "South Carolina",
           "Georgia",         "Florida",        "Ohio",
           "Indiana",         "Illinois",       "Michigan",
           "Wisconsin",       "Kentucky",       "Tennessee",
           "Alabama",         "Mississippi",    "Arkansas",
           "Louisiana",       "Oklahoma",       "Texas",
           "Minnesota",       "Iowa",           "Missouri",
           "North Dakota",    "South Dakota",   "Nebraska",
           "Kansas",          "Montana",        "Idaho",
           "Wyoming",         "Colorado",       "New Mexico",
           "Arizona",         "Utah",           "Nevada",
           "Washington",      "Oregon",         "California",
           "Alaska",          "Hawaii",         "District of Columbia",
           "Virgin Islands",  "Puerto Rico",    "New Mexico",
           "Pacific Islands", "Mississippi",    "Florida",
           "Puerto Rico",     "Arizona",        "California",
           "Texas",           "Utah",           "New Mexico",
           "Colorado",        "South Carolina", "Louisiana",
           "Georgia",         "Arkansas",       "Nevada"};
    }

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < areaNumbers.length; i++)    
        if areanumbers[i] == int area;

    break;

}
```

Comment: Please, post properly formatted code. People are here to help, be kind towards their eyes!

Comment: For starters, you can't declare "1" as a variable.

Comment: What are you hoping `if areanumbers[i]==int area;` will do for you?

Comment: @pamphlet I want basically when the user puts in the social security numbers the first 3 numbers are the area for it,  to be found it the array int[]areaNumbers

Comment: Your code looks syntactically wrong. you are making a comparison between a value and a statement.

Comment: say my social security numbers is 158-27-4321 my area number would be 158 and this correspond to new jersey i want to use a loop that will search my int areaNumbers array and the  give me the location being new jersey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest creating a HashMap of your area information. A Map object would allow you to map a U.S. State or Territory to the number corresponding to what you parse.

```
Map<Integer, String> areaMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>(); 
areaMap.put(new Integer(3), "New Hampshire"); 
areaMap.put(new Integer(7), "Maine"); 
areaMap.put(new Integer(9), "Vermont"); 
// and so on...
```

Then use your original code...

```
// Get the area number (the first 3 digits of the SSN)
int area = Integer.parseInt(ssn.substring(0, 3));

String associatedArea = areaMap.get(new Integer(area));
System.out.println("You are from: " + associatedArea);
```

If you *must* use a loop, try something like this:

```
String originArea = "";
for(int i=0; i<areaNumbers.length; i++) {
    int compareMe = areaNumbers[i];
    if( compareMe == area) { 
        originArea = locations[i];
        break; 
    }
}

System.out.println("You are from: " + originArea);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you try a `HashMap<Integer, String>`? Use the areaNumber as key and the location as value. You will not need to loop through the areaNumbers, you can just use the map.get()-method.

**EDIT:**
If you wish to use a loop, use that one:

```
for(int i = 0;i<areaNumbers.length;i++){
  if(areaNumbers[i] == area){
     String location = locations[i];
     // you found the right location, do what you want with it ;-)
     break;
  }  
}
```

Comment: I think OP would benefit more from learning how to use a loop.

Comment: Edited my question to provide what you need.

Answer (score 1):

1. Don't store your data in an arrays, you are definitely using key-value, so use a `Map`, for instance a `HashMap` or even `ImmutableMap` from the `Guava`.
2. Then, having the map use a `containsKey(Object o)` method to check if it's there, or simply `get()` it and check if it's not a `null`.
3. You can format your string, no need to check it by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me you looking for something like:

```
String location = null;

for (i=0; i < areaNumbers.length; i++)
    if areanumbers[i] == area;
        location = locations[i];
```

And the end of this location will be the location associated with the area code, or null if it wasn't found in the `areaNumbers` array.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I can see:

First, `areanumbers[]` is not the same as `areaNumbers[]`, so what you have in your `if` statement at the bottom doesn't refer to the array of integers you constructed above.
Second, some code is missing in your check at the bottom.  You'll probably want something like:

```
int i;

for (i = 0; i < areaNumbers.length; i++)
{    
    if (areaNumbers[i] == area)
    {
        // do something with location[i]
    }
}
```

Third, I'd look into other structures as L Butz mentioned (if you don't *have* to use loops, of course!)  Likely easier all around.

Comment: Yes I have to make it a loop and I think I understand how to get the area to correspond to the area array but the second part confuses me as to how I make my area number match up with the corresponding element in location array

Comment: All you have to do to "make them match up" is list the array elements in an order so that they match up. If `areaNumber` 134 indeed corresponds to `location` New Jersey, you're in good shape. Then `areaNumber[7]` will correspond to `location[7]`, `areaNumber[31]` will correspond to `location[31]`, etc.  That's why I (and others) said to do something with `location[i]` once you've found that `areaNumbers[i]` matches the one you want.